# Firefox adds random scripts on every page load

Tags: firefox, security

I noticed today that Firefox adds a bunch of scripts to every pageload. Here's a screenshot:[image]
I checked the add-ons. It's just Adblocker plus, Firebug, colorzilla, lastpass, screengrab, share-a-holic. So, nothing suspicious there. I have Microsoft Security Essentials and scans are clean. What might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go take a look at the script address itself, at `http://i.824js.info/opt_1377519250520/opt_content.js?partner=824&channel=824p500&appTitle=` ([link](http://i.824js.info/opt_1377519250520/opt_content.js?partner=824&channel=824p500&appTitle=)), there's a comment at the top:

```
/** See http://www.dealply.com/ for details. *//* JavaScriptJsTagUrl = DealPlyScriptTagUrlMagic; */
```

A quick search indicates that this may be [a form of adware](http://botcrawl.com/how-to-remove-dealply-adware/) - removal instructions are available at the linked site.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But then I am surprised why MSE didn't find anything while Malwarebyte came up with several malwares.